# Specify app scopes in php facebook sdk 4.0.0 or greater

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the new php sdk for facebook (>= 4.0.0) and I am trying to figure out where to specify the **scope** of my requests to the graph api. Like, where do I specify I want the`publish_actions` so that the user can authorize me for that when logging in?

In [this here link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/4.0.0) it says:

> You must have requested the publish_actions scope when logging in the
>   user for this to work.

But how can that be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

It's just like in previous versions of the PHP SDK, you load the scope into the getLoginUrl function

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('your redirect URL here');
$scope = array('publish_actions');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($scope);
```

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L85