# How can i get facebook events for user using php?

Tags: php, facebook

I am creating a website in which i need to fetch name of events for user logged in.
I am using Graph Api. I am new in Graph Api. currently i am using this code :

```
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app-id','secret-key' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('redirect_uri' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
$request1 = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/'.$fbid.'/events'
);
$response1 = $request1->execute();
$graphObject1 = $response1->getGraphObject();
 print_r($graphObject1->getProperty('data'));die();
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

But i am getting blank page.Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `user_events` permission contained in the Access Token you're using. As far as I can see you're not requesting it during the Login process.

Have a look at

- [Specify app scopes in php facebook sdk 4.0.0 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590472/specify-app-scopes-in-php-facebook-sdk-4-0-0-or-greater)
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/#Reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens