# Scope parameter is ignored by facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am trying to use Facebooks PHP SDK to login to my page. However, Facebook ignores the permissions given as an array in getLoginUrl()

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(
    ['publish_actions']
);
```

The login url looks like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=206265226055767&redirect_uri=http://host.tld/remote/gateway.php&state=67096befe627aa603cb086da681626c1&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.23&scope=publish_actions
```

However, Facebook still ask for my public_profile and my email

- I have administrator privileges
- The app is still in development mode

My Question is why Facebook ignores the scope parameter on the oauth login dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this code:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'publish_actions',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Not sure if it works the same way with the PHP SDK 4.x though, but you can try this:

```
$scope = array('publish_actions');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($scope);
```

...from the well upvoted answer in this thread: [Specify app scopes in php facebook sdk 4.0.0 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590472/specify-app-scopes-in-php-facebook-sdk-4-0-0-or-greater)

Of course you can also write it like this:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('publish_actions'));
```

Not sure if it helps in your case, the literal array definition should definitely work in PHP...but you never know ;)

Comment: Same result. The scopes parameters is part of the login url but the app doesn't request the permissions mentioned in the scope.
Your second example is equal to mine

Comment: i get the following error: "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration" - make sure your app settings are correct

Comment: I removed the redirect_uri parameter. This is the original url with redirect_uri parameter: https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=206265226055767&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmark4.de%2Fremote%2Fgateway.php&state=30dbdd8e1ef715b9404914c4361b9f57&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.23&scope=manage_pages

Comment: and you are surely trying with your account, which is the app admin? there should be a red banner in the auth window saying that you need to go through review. does that show up?

Comment: I know. But there isn't any hint for the review process. And yes i created the app :)

Answer (score 0):

**It's not being ignored**

Initially Facebook shows a dialog so that the user can approve permissions to app, like profile, email, friends etc. What you're experiencing is specific to the publishing permissions like `publish_actions`.

Publishing permissions prompt a **second dialog** for the user to approve such permissions, which you'll get right after you take action about the permission request in the 1st dialog.

So,don't worry, it's not you, it's them.

Straight from the Facebook Permissions doc - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#optimizing

Hoping that helped.